# Error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when display image

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code has been working for few months without any problem. Now this page does not work and the problem from php code but I dont know where

```html
 <?php


 $query = "SELECT * FROM offerimage order by name";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
 echo "<table>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       echo "<tr>";
 
 
  $image = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
 
 
//echo '<br></br>'; 
echo $image;
echo '<br></br>'; 
    echo "</tr>";
  
    }
} else {

 echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

I GET THIS ERROR

"ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

[image: this is page of the error]

Comment: Commenting here since @IdontDownVote correctly pointed out it wasn't an answer. You need to debug from the logs to get the error. Doesn't matter if other code is working fine, if you want to understand what is wrong with that page and that script you need to check the server logs and see what error appears when you load the page.

Comment: Is there even an error in the code? From the message, it seems like the page itself isn't working.

Comment: the code work fine for few months. now it is not working. I delete all images from DB and then I insert new image. the code work fine and display image I notice if total size of images is big, I will get same error

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you output something when the query returns no rows, since that's probably the cause?

Also you should have the images inside a `<td>` element.

*Edited to show row-by-row retrieval of images. Assumes the database table `offerimage` has a unique integer ID (like an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column) named `id`, change queries to match the actual table definition.*

```
<?php

// get array of offerimage IDs ordered by name
$query = "SELECT id FROM offerimage order by name";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$ids = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ids[] = (int)$row['id'];
}

if (count($ids) > 0) {
    // display each image
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $query = "SELECT image FROM offerimage WHERE id = {$id}";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
        echo "</td></tr>";

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<p>No offers found.</p>";
}
```

Other suggestions: Don't use `SELECT *` if you only need one column. Use `SELECT image` instead.

Check for errors when making the database connection (you don't show that code) and from the query, use `error_log()` or send to the browser so you can see if something went wrong there.

Comment: I get same error. I already have error connection message but I did not write in Q. Also, when I delete "echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'" height="100" width="100"/>';" the page will load with out any image from DB otherwise I will get the page error as posted in Q

Comment: I delete all images from DB and then I insert new image. the code work fine and display image I notice if total size of images is big, I will get same error

Comment: Seems like you are running out of memory. If the images have IDs you could select those (only), `SELECT id FROM offerimage ORDER BY name`, then loop over those fetching the images one by one, so you aren't trying to get all of them in memory at once. In the `while` loop do another query `"SELECT image FROM offerimage WHERE id = {$id}"` to get one image at a time.

Comment: thank you for response. Do you mean to keep the new select in var and then encode that var ? I tried but it does not run correctly

Comment: Then you need to debug it line by line. If you can’t use error logging put `echo “found “.$result->num_rows;”; exit();` lines (for example) to see where it’s breaking.

Comment: I already debug it before. If I delete this line "$image ='<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'" height="350" width="200"/>';"   it will load the page but with out any image and no error. It seems the problem from this line. Also I create a new table and I get same issue.

Comment: You could post your database table schema, at least the relevant columns. I don't know what's in the `image` column, assuming a binary blob of JPEG image data. Possibly you have an image in the wrong format, possibly you have a huge image that causes out of memory or other problem. Generally it's a bad idea to store images in the database, better to save them as regular files and store a reference to them in the database. I can't help anymore with the information you have posted. Have you looked at the PHP error logs?

Comment: First, Thank you for helping. I store in DB LONGBLOB. As I mentioned, the code was working fine for more than 6 months and now it does not work. The size of each pic no more than 400 KB and the table has 13 images. If id keep only 2 images, I will get them in web page otherwise I will get error ( as showed in first post). Now, I changed the code to store image in folder in store location in DB and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by save images in folder and then save image location in DB.